# Обязательно ли для константного объекта перегружать методы как константные?

Tags: c++, const

У меня есть абстрактный класс к которому я буду апкастинг делать использовать его в другом классе.

Я хочу в классе-пользователе объявить указатель на данный абстрактный класс как константный (по аналогии с readonly в C# - чтобы я не смог ничего изменить в данном классе, а мог только использовать его).

Обязательно ли делать константные перегрузки виртуальных методов абстрактного класса, или же я как-то смогу достучаться до неконстантных методов из константного указателя на данный класс?

Comment: Вдумайтесь в свой вопрос - с одной стороны, "чтобы я не смог ничего изменить", с другой - "достучаться до неконстантных методов", которые и призваны *менять* состояние объекта. Вы уж выберите что-то одно. Потому что хотя извернуться и можно, но при этом вы полностью теряете смысл константности.

Comment: Вы не можете вызывать не константные методы у константного экземпляра класса, если вопрос об этом.

Comment: Неконстантные методы призваны (должно быть так)  менять состояние обьекта. Если  указатель только для чтения, то не нужно достучаться до неконстантных методов.  Если один класс только использует другой класс, то можно подумать еще о закрытом(защищенном) наследовании.   И, к выражению в скобках...  через указатель не сможете ничего изменять в классе, можете изменять обьект...

Comment: Благодарю всех, понял.